# How to input the value of an array to my database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

i design a html output table that goes into my database to pick out it values from in which i also include the submit button in other for users for choose from arrays of values, here is the sql table [image: the sql table where i picked the value from]

so here is the code i use to output the table

```
 <table class="table table-hover mails m-0 table table-actions-bar">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Level</th>
             <th>Amount</th>
             <th>Potential Earning</th>
             <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <?php
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($levels); $i++) {
             $level = $levels[$i];
         ?>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <?php echo ($level->getLevel()); ?>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <?php echo ($level->getAmount()); ?>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <?php echo ($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?>
             </td>
             <td>
                 <button type="submit" value="Add Project" style="background-color:steelblue; color:white">Add Project</button>
             </td>
         </tr>
     <?php
         }
     ?>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

[image: here is the output of the table just as i mention that all it value is from my database]

But, the only issue am having is how the the add project button will be able to submit the actual amount to the user database, please help

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the amount to the link attached to the button. This method will work if you decide not to use a form. If you decide to use a form, simply add a hidden input field called amount and parse the value there

```
 <table class="table table-hover mails m-0 table table-actions-bar">
 <thead>
 <tr>
 <th>Level</th>
 <th>Amount</th>
 <th>Potential Earning</th>
 <th>Action</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <?php
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($levels); $i++) {
 $level = $levels[$i];
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <?php echo ($level->getLevel()); ?>
 </td>
 <td>
 <?php echo ($level->getAmount()); ?>
 </td>
 <td>
 <?php echo ($level->getPotentialEarning()); ?>
 </td>
 <td>
 <a type="submit" href="script.php?amount=<?php echo ($level->getAmount()); ?>" class="btn btn-default" value="Add Project" style="background-color:steelblue; color:white">Add Project</button>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

On your php save, you can check as:

```
if(isset($_GET['amount']) && is_numeric($_GET['amount'])){
  $amount = $_GET['amount'];
}
```